# Coinbase transfer between accounts returns "Not found"

Tags: node.js, coinbase-api

I'm trying to transfer BTC and BCH between accounts. Looking through the documentation I have found the following:
https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#transfer-money-between-accounts

First off I believe there is an error in their example, as the "currency" property is mandatory, it gives an error when not providing it.

But after adding the currency, every request I make returns with "Not found".

I'm using the node client, but I think the problem is higher up.

This is the request I'm doing:

```javascript
const Client        = require('coinbase').Client;

let client = new Client({'apiKey': 'xxxx', 'apiSecret': 'xxx'});

client.getAccounts({}, function(err, accounts) {

    let btc_account = null;
    let bch_account = null;

    for(account of accounts) {
        if(account.currency == "BTC") {
            btc_account = account;
        } else if(account.currency == "BCH") {
            bch_account = account;
        }
    }

    var options = {'to': bch_account.id, 'amount': btc_account.balance.amount, 'currency': "BTC"};

    btc_account.transferMoney(options, function(err, tx) {
        if(err) {
            console.log("ERROR during transfer", err);
            return
        }
        console.log(tx);
    });
});
```

Doing this returns me with:

`ERROR during transfer NotFound: Not found`

After doing some debugging, I found it tries to do the request with the following options:

```
url: 'https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/xxx/transactions'
body: '{"to":"xxx","amount":"0.00072256","currency":"BTC","type":"transfer"}'
```

(obfuscated the actual account.id's)

And the actual response from their API is:

```json
{"errors":[{"id":"not_found","message":"Not found"}]}
```

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: [Fran Meggs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15088063) wrote an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66083925) saying "Are you POSTing rather than GETing on the request ?"

Comment: Can confirm this is occurring in the .NET offering, and definitely `POST`ing... surprising to see a $100B company produce such a questionable API.

Comment: This is sort of a thing w/ Coinbase, it seems: https://www.reddit.com/r/CoinBase/comments/nczfdg/coinbase_support_has_repeatedly_ignored_requests/