# Converting from BTC to another currency

Tags: coinbase-api

From Coinbase API can you convert from Bitcoin to, for example, USDC? I cannot see any reference but I have this feature on the app. I wonder if API supports (or expects support for) this operation, or it just that I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Coinbase API PRO Documentation](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#stablecoin-conversions) you can create a conversion by:

**HTTP REQUEST**
POST /conversions

**API KEY PERMISSIONS**
This endpoint requires the “trade” permission.

**Request**

{
"from": "USD",
"to": "USDC",
"amount": "10000.00"
}

**PARAMETERS**

from:   A valid currency id
to:     A valid currency id
amount: Amount of from to convert to to

Probably more of a question of what the valid currencies are

Comment: Just to mention that this feature (stablecoins conversion) is not available on Coinbase API but included on Coinbase PRO API.

Comment: Are there any other _non_ PRO ways to transfer from one currency to another?

Comment: Not that I know of sorry

Comment: Is there a way to *list* existing conversions? I'm trying to reconstruct a Coinbase Pro account's history and I can't figure out how to query stablecoin versions that have already happened.

Comment: But that's just for Stable coins, not BTC to ETH etc no ?

Answer (score 1):

Without using CoinbasePro API but only Coinbase API from webapp that are the endpoints you need to call:

1. Have to know base_id of crypto that you want to sell and base_id of
   crypto want to buy. You can know it by call GET
   "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/
   /assets/prices?base=USD&filter=holdable&resolution=latest" and get
   from response the "base_id" of your currencies.
2. Make an order by calling POST "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trade"
   with a request body in json like this:

   { 'amount': [amount that you want to convert], 'amount_asset':
   [currency of amount that you want to convert], 'amount_from':
   'input', 'source_asset': ["base_id" of crypto that you want to
   sell], 'target_asset': ["base_id" of crypto that you want to buy] }
3. If previous POST "/trade" response code is 201, you have to get the
   "id" value of response's json and do a commit of your order by
   calling POST "https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trades/[id of json
   response of previous https://api.coinbase.com/v2/trade POST"]/commit". If
   the response code of this POST commit is 201, your exchange is
   started and if there are not error in coinbase, your conversion is
   done!

Comment: Is that a trade (where you have to pay fees) or a conversion (free)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a reference for this in the Coinbase API documentation:
https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#transfer-money-between-accounts

But as I stated in my question, it unfortunately doesn't seem to work:
[Coinbase transfer between accounts returns "Not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323106/coinbase-transfer-between-accounts-returns-not-found)